# Are Oktoberfest beers available in Germany before the official start of the festival?

Tags: german-beers, germany

In the US where I live, fall brings beers labelled "Oktoberfest", usually Bavarian Märzenbiers.  I like this style and look forward to it.

This year it happens that I'm going to be passing through Munich a few days before the start of their [Oktoberfest](http://www.munichsoktoberfest.com/).  It'd be great to be able to sample Oktoberfest beers fresh out of the tap where they're made, rather than waiting for whatever makes it across the Atlantic to me later.  Am I likely to find any Oktoberfest beers in the Munich airport in the week before the festival, or is that date the "debut" and I'll just have to settle for other German beers when I'm there?

Comment: Hardship, I know, having to "settle" for other German beers. :-)  But I'm wondering if I still have a chance to sample something new.

Comment: 1. What do you mean saying "Oktoberfest beers"? 2. There is more than one Oktoberfest in Germany (surely the one in Munich in THE Oktoberfest).

Comment: Here in the US in the fall, beers labelled "Oktoberfest" become available.  I'm assuming that they are tied to the event in Germany.  I asked specifically about Munich because that's where I'm going to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you will find any Oktoberfest beer at the airport but they are available several weeks before "official" start in big groceries or beer shops.  Hacker-Pschorr Oktoberfest Märzen, Paulaner Oktoberfest and Löwenbräu Oktoberfestbier were already available three weeks  ago even in nothern Germany.

Answer (score 0):

You can even buy the Löwenbräu beer easily on Amazon so **YES** you can buy it.
[beer Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/L%C3%B6wenbr%C3%A4u-257885-Oktoberfestbier-24-0-5/dp/B01LB4KPGM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1474036523&sr=8-2&keywords=L%C3%B6wenbr%C3%A4u)